# Nautilus: how can I get rid of the second "Files" menu item?

Tags: nautilus, 17.04

I have a problem with my nautilus...

[image: Screenshot]

as you can see, on the picture (the one I circled in red) there are 2 "Files" menu items, and I want one of them to disappear...do you know how to do that?

I have tried everything to remove it but until now I am still unable to solve it...

Anyway i am using Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Thanks for correcting my grammar :)
so no one knows about this ???